# Pascal's triangle without using arrays (only loops)

Tags: java

I am trying to output Pascal's triangle with asterisks (*). This is my code:

```
public static void main(String [] arg)
{
    int n=3;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        boolean b=true;
        for(int k=0;k<i*2+1;k++)
        {
            if(b)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
                b=false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
                b=true;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
}
```

I have rechecked several times and failed to find any error.
Also let me know whether the if-block is implemented correctly.
The following code is not giving the required output as below:

```
     *  
   *   *  
*    *    *
```

Comment: What is the output it's giving?

Comment: I know for a fact that this is the tipical exercise for homework when someone is learning to program. I did it myself in school so you should just learn for yourself.

Comment: * ** *** Its giving me this output.

Comment: Everything is all on one line because nowhere in your for-loop do you do a `println()`

Comment: What [JoaoFilipeClementeMartins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2859926/joaofilipeclementemartins) says, and use a debugger.

Comment: Your output is currently on one line. So you probably need a System.out.println(); statement somewhere. Try putting it after the third FOR loop.

Comment: Ya got it. I had put the println() outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `System.out.println()` statement is outside of your for loop instead of inside.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        boolean b = true;
        for (int k = 0; k < i * 2 + 1; k++) {
            if (b) {
                System.out.print("*");
                b = false;
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
                b = true;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" "); // called only once

    // output is
    //   *  * * * * *
```

Just move it inside the close brace and your program will work.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        boolean b = true;
        for (int k = 0; k < i * 2 + 1; k++) {
            if (b) {
                System.out.print("*");
                b = false;
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
                b = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" "); // called once for each iteration
    }

    // output is
    //   * 
    //  * * 
    // * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

make inner loop reverse

```
for(int j=n-i;j>0;j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
```

this should print from 3 starts then 2 then 1 star

Comment: This won't help his problem, which is that all of his output is on a single line.